# Recover Nethack game in OS X (NetHackCocoa)

Tags: technical-issues, nethack

I finally get a good character going, and NetHackCocoa decides to crash on me and then show this lovely little message whenever I try to restart:

[image: Destroy old game]

Naturally I click 'No' and then attempt to find the nethack recover application that I've heard so much about.

However, to my surprise I can't seem to find it anywhere.  I've looked in the NetHackCocoa.app package and in my ~/Library/NetHackCocoa directory.  I made a complete backup of that area...as much as I wanted to avoid save-scumming I think that recovering from a crash doesn't count :/.

Anyway, in my ~/Library/NetHackCocoa are a bunch of files with my username and various numbers appended, followed by a bones level, logfile, paniclog, perm_lock, and record files.  Also an empty save/ directory.

I've seen other people who have tried recovering say that the game is thinking they're cheating...so I'd like to avoid that if possible...

---

**Edit**

Attempted to use the tty version of recover, met with the following error as well:

```
Cannot open level 0 for (uid)(username)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the unix/windows version you can do this by using the Nethack program. The syntax for it is

```
nethack -uCHARNAME
```

Replace CHARNAME with what ever your character name was.

If you got the above message in your question doing this:

```
Cannot open level 0 for (uid)(username)
```

I would check the file directory for a file that looks like this:

```
loginUserName-charName.0
```

loginUserName = Your login username
charName = Your character's name

Check the permissions on the file and make sure that you have access to the file. Other then that I do not believe there is much you can do. If you have a backup the file I would try to replace it as it seems to be the culprit.

Comment: Permissions seem to be OK.

Comment: @espais did you try nethack -u command? If so what was the error message you got from it.

Comment: I think the problem is more tied to the Mac port.  I can run Nethack in tty mode just fine (nethack -u just starts a new game).  The Mac app runs separately from tty nethack.

Comment: @espais only thing I can suggest is .zip up your files. Post it somewhere and send me a link and I'll do the recovery on a Win 32 machine.

Comment: I actually have a VM setup with Windows.  Is there an easy way to go about doing that?  I can just do it myself..

Comment: @espais download the win32 binaries, and in the command prompt use the command nethack -uCHARNAME. (Replace CHARNAME with the character's name)

Comment: Ok, I copied all of my backup files to the windows nethack directory.  Nethack just seems to ignore my -u command and asks to start a new character...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6209/discussion-between-halfwarr-and-espais)

Answer (score 1):

This may not be relevant, but I once confuse myself endlessly because there was an old Nethack process still running in the background somewhere. Make sure this isn't the case!